# SQL Azure unexpected database deletion/recreation

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I've been scratching my head on this for hours, but can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

**Here's our project basic setup:**

- MVC 3.0 Project with ASP.NET Membership
- Entity Framework 4.3, Code First approach
- Local environment: local SQL Server with 2 MDF database files attached (aspnet.mdf + entities.mdf)
- Server environment: Windows Azure + 2 SQL Azure databases (aspnet and entities)

**Here's what we did:**

- Created local and remote databases, modified web.config to use SQLEXPRESS connection strings in debug mode and SQL Azure connection strings in release mode
- Created a `SampleData` class extending `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Entities>` with a `Seed` method to seed data.
- Used `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new Models.SampleData());` in `Application_Start` to seed data to our databases.
- Ran app locally - tables were created and seeded, all OK.
- Deployed, ran remote app -  tables were created and seeded, all OK.
- Added pre-processor directives to stop destroying the Entity database at each application start on our remote Azure environment:

  ```
  #if DEBUG
      System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new Models.SampleData());
  #else
      System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<Entities>(null);
  #endif
  ```

**Here's where it got ugly**

- We enabled Migrations using NuGet, with `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`
- Everything was running smooth and nice. We left it cooking for a couple days
- Today, we noticed an unknown bug on the Azure environment:

  - we have several classes deriving from a superclass `SuperClass`
  - the corresponding Entity table stores all of these objects in the same `SuperClass` table, using a discriminator to know which column to feed from when loading the various classes
  - While the loading went just fine before today, it doesn't anymore. We get the following error message:

    ```
    The 'Foo' property on 'SubClass1' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.
    ```
  - After a quick check, our `SuperClass` table has columns `Foo` and `Foo1`. Logical enough, since `SuperClass` has 2 subclasses `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`, each with a `Foo` property. In our case, `Foo` is NULL but `Foo1` has an `int32` value. So the problem is not with the database - rather, it would seem that the link between our Model and Database has been lost. The discriminator logic was corrupted.
- Trying to find indications on what could've gone wrong, we noticed several things:

  - Even though we never performed any migration on the SQL Azure Entity database, the database now has a `_MigrationHistory` table
  - The `_MigrationHistory` table has one record:

    ```
    MigrationID: 201204102350574_InitialCreate
    CreatedOn: 4/10/2012 11:50:57 PM
    Model: <Binary data>
    ProductVersion: 4.3.1
    ```
  - Looking at other tables, most of them were emptied when this migration happened. Only the tables that were initially seeded with `SampleData` remained untouched.
  - Checking in with the SQL Azure Management portal, our Entity database shows the following creation date: 4/10/2012 23:50:55.

**Here is our understanding**

- For some reason, SQL Azure deleted and recreated our database
- The _MigrationHistory table was created in the process, registering a starting point to test the model against for future migrations

**Here are our Questions**

- Who / What triggered the database deletion / recreation?
- How could EF re-seed our sample data since `Application_Start` has `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<Entities>(null);`?

---

**EDIT:** Looking at what could've gone wrong, we noticed one thing we didn't respect in this SQL Azure [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/13/mvc-code-first-azure-part-1-local-development.aspx): we didn't remove `PersistSecurityInfo` from our SQL Azure Entity database connection string after the database was created. Can't see why on Earth it could have caused the problem, but still worth mentioning...

Comment: I had similar experience, when I logged into sql management portal my database disappeared. I still have no clue how that happened. I must watch out after production launch of my app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the cause of our problem. In case anybody wonders: we hadn't made any Azure deployment since the addition of the pre-processor directives. MS must have restarted the machine our VM resided on, and the new VM recreated the database using see data.

Lesson learned: always do frequent Azure deployments.